# Can’t see user-defined database “types" in pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Is there a graphical way to create/manipulate/view special database types in PgAdmin?

For example, in PostgreSQL we have:

`CREATE TYPE compfoo AS (f1 int, f2 text);`

I’ve noticed pgAdmin almost shows everything graphically, such as triggers, views, functions, and of course tables, but I couldn’t find the types that I created.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You just need to enable viewing types through menu File → Options... → Browser and checking `Types`:

[image]

According to pgAdmin's [documentation](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.14/options-tab3.html):

> The list of check boxes is used to select which object types to show
>   in the browser tree. By default, only the most commonly used object
>   types are shown. Reducing the number of object types shown can
>   increase the speed of pgAdmin when querying the system catalogs. Use
>   the Default button to reset the list to its default settings.

Comment: Thanks... just a note: for PgAdmin III, you need to access this via pgAdmin3 → Preferences → Browser(tab)

Comment: This works, but they still don't show up in the Graphical Query Builder.